# Filling in a datetime field as empty

Tags: sql, datetime

I need to add a new record to a database and one of the columns in my table is 'paymentDate', which is a "DateTime" field.  Now the record I need to add is one in  which the paymentDate is not known. I can't put in 'NULL' as SQL says 'Column 'paymentDate' cannot be null'. Also the '""' doesn't work in a datetime field.

Comment: Did you create that table? Declare the `paymentDate` column as nullable, then you _can_ insert NULL values.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `paymentDate` column and you don't know the date, then the column should allow `NULL` values.  So, you should fix the data model:

```
alter table t alter column paymentDate datetime;
```

This will remove the not-NULL constraint, so you can add the data that you have.

I would be a little cautious, though.  Why are you trying to add a row with an unknown payment date, if the designer of the table thought the value should never be `NULL`?

Comment: Oh, it is a common training database available for beginners - think it is called the 'classic models' - not a real life one!